# Are CNNs reliable when dealing with distance between two objects in the image?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, cnn

I am building a CNN application in which the output is a continuous value(regression). And this value is very much related to the distance between two specific objects in the input image. Detecting those specific objects should not be an issue. But carrying the distance information in fairly accurate manner into the network is doubting me.

These are the key points according to me:

1. I did read CNNs are translation invariant. That is to some extent kernels do not carry positional information of the features.
2. One approach would be to have a very large size kernel which can fit both the objects inside together. This seems to have two issues. One is of course large kernels. Another is, it might need kernels for every possible separation value between two objects. Hence this does not seem to be reliable.

So am I having a misconception? Or else what can be done to get along with this?

Comment: This is weird, because the distance of the objects also depends on the distance where you take the picture from, and this cannot be guessed just with the information given by the image.

Comment: Well, I only need the pixel distance in the image. That's okay if I don't get actual distance.

Comment: Ok. I still don't understand one thing. If you can perform object recognition with a CNN to the two objects, why don't you just compute the centers and then compute pixel distance? I think that the hard thing is the object recognition part, but you say it should not be an issue

Comment: Yes what you mentioned can be good approach for certain cases. Coming to the second point, CNNs are very good at recognizing the features but don't seem to find spatial relationships between them. Manually calculating the centers won't seem to work since the features will be decided automatically by the network. I just wanted to know if there a way by which the spatial information is preserved along the network.